# How to categorize a column with regex patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

- My question is how to put some value in a new column, based on the content in another column.
- In my specific case, I have a dataframe, with a column named `'Flop'`, that has string values in 3 different category
- I can find these 'categories' with regex, and based on each category, I wanna create another column called `'Suitedness'` with the name of each category.

A example of my df is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Flop']=['As 5d 7c','As 9s 3s','8c 7d 5s','8d, As, Js','Qs Ts 8d','7s 2s 2d']
```

### Initial dataframe

```py
       Flop
   As 5d 7c
   As 9s 3s
   8c 7d 5s
 8d, As, Js
   Qs Ts 8d
   7s 2s 2d
```

I solve the problem in this way:

```
Monotone = df[df['Flop'].str.contains('(\ws\s){2}\ws',na=False)]
Monotone['Suitedness']= 'Monotone'
Rainbow = df[df['Flop'].str.contains('(\wc\s.*)+|(\w.\s\wc.*)+|(\w[s,d,c]\s\w[s,d,c]\s\wc)+',na=False)]
Rainbow['Suitedness']= 'Rainbow'
DoubleSuited = df[df['Flop'].str.contains('((\ws\s){2}\w[d,c])+|(\ws\s\w[d,c]\s\ws)+|(\w[d,c]\s\ws\s\ws)+',na=False)]
DoubleSuited['Suitedness']= 'Double Suited'
df2 = pd.concat([Monotone,Rainbow,DoubleSuited])
df2 = df2.sort_index()
```

- This code creates 3 different dataframes, and concatenates them.

  - This solution works, but is inelegant.
  - I'm looking for a cleaner solution.
- As well, my regex syntax is a little messy.

  - The 3 categories are based on the letter 's', 1, 2 or 3 's'
  - I'd also like tips on better regex syntax.

### Final dataframe

```py
     Flop     Suitedness
 As 5d 7c        Rainbow
 As 9s 3s       Monotone
 8c 7d 5s        Rainbow
 Qs Ts 8d  Double Suited
 7s 2s 2d  Double Suited
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using your sample data
- This solution doesn't alter the regular expressions being used, it only streamlines setting the `'Suitedness'` of each string in `'Flop'`

  - See the [SO: Regex Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) for ideas to make the regular expressions more efficient
  - Visit [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions.
- Create a dictionary with your regulars expressions and associated phrases
- Use [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a list comprehension, which returns a list with the correct `Suitedness` or an empty list if there's not match with [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

  - With the expectation that there will only be a single match, or no match, [pandas.Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) is used to return the value at index 0.

    - A list index selection won't work for cases where the list is empty (e.g. `[][0]`) because it results in an `IndexError`
- If you are not concerned with `NaN` values, use `df = df.dropna()` to remove those rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# create a dict of mappings
mapping = {'(\ws\s){2}\ws': 'Monotone',
           '(\wc\s.*)+|(\w.\s\wc.*)+|(\w[s,d,c]\s\w[s,d,c]\s\wc)+': 'Rainbow',
           '((\ws\s){2}\w[d,c])+|(\ws\s\w[d,c]\s\ws)+|(\w[d,c]\s\ws\s\ws)+': 'Double Suited'}

# apply a list comprehension
df['Suitedness'] = df.Flop.apply(lambda x: [v for k, v in mapping.items() if re.match(k, x)]).explode()

# display(df)
       Flop     Suitedness
   As 5d 7c        Rainbow
   As 9s 3s       Monotone
   8c 7d 5s        Rainbow
 8d, As, Js            NaN
   Qs Ts 8d  Double Suited
   7s 2s 2d  Double Suited
```